# Angular 7 ngFor in ngIf

Tags: angular

I try to make ngFor statment in ngIf block but doesn't work. Code is following:

```
<!-- This work -->
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(20)">ok</div>
</div>

<!-- This work -->
<div *ngIf="true">
    <div>ok</div>
</div>

<!-- This doesn't work -->
<div *ngIf="true">
    <div *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(20)">Why??</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When I paste this code into [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-ppeekt?file=src/app/app.component.html) it works for me.

Comment: It does work. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This not have any problem, I have it replicated with angular 7.2.0, and works perfectly.

Maybe you can add some evidence or the error shown?

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your html code in jsfiddle html block and click on run

visit https://jsfiddle.net/

It works properly